# How to test multiple data sources in single application?

Tags: spring, multiple-databases, spring-boot-test

I have a spring boot application, which is connecting to two different data sources. (All the connection, URL, other DB properties are different and configure in application.properties file)

I am not able to test this application because mockito or any other testing framework wouldn't be able to distinguish between two different data sources.

Please suggest how to test this application.

Comment: Wouldn't you be mocking the DB calls? Or are you talking about integration testing?

Comment: integration testing and  while try to mock datasources it will not able to distinguish between datasources ; because it only understand the dependency by type.

Comment: Are you using an in-memory database to mock the calls? Or are you using when().thenReturn() pattern to mock your DB calls?

Comment: nope its external DB and using when().thenReturn() way...

Comment: If it's when().thenReturn() way, then why do you need to differentiate between the 2 data sources?

Comment: Because I am connecting to two different data sources in my application,So the name are different.Spring injecting them based on Name but Mockito can't..